# Transparent animated gif hogging CPU

Tags: css, animated-gif

I would like to overlay a transparent animated gif (transparency in the CSS, not in the file itself), but when I do, it draws a huge amount of constant CPU usage (according to OSX Activity Monitor). I'm curious as to what is causing this, and if there may be a workaround.

Here is the CSS being applied to the element:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0.05;
```

The gif is 6 960x540px frames, looping at around 24 frames-per-second. No animations are being applied.

Comment: We're going to need more information than this if you want us to help. What CSS is applied to the element? Are you animating CSS properties on it? Did you use some browser's profiler to make the assumption?

Comment: @JacqueGoupil added some extra info to my question.